# String comparison C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, string-comparison

I am creating a web app in C# with connection to a SQL Server database.

I need to compare data from database to string in my app and here is my problem.

I suppose it is a problem with encoding so I tried few ways like functions `Normalize()`, few kinds of string comparisons but it's never been working.

I had changed type in my database from `char` to `nvarchar` and it wasn't working too.

Here is a piece of my code, do you have any ideas?

```
query = "SELECT status_name FROM quizgame.dbo.uzytkownicy AS u WHERE u.nazwa = @nazwa";
cmd2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, conn);

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nazwa", DBNull.Value);
else
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nazwa", name);

object scalar2 = cmd2.ExecuteScalar();

if(scalar2 != null)
    user_status = scalar2.ToString();
```

And when I try to compare two strings with method `Equals` which is completely the same the `bool` result is always false.

Comment: Beware. A Char(x) database columns adds spaces to your string to reach the length x. When you transform the column to nvarchar(x) these spaces are not removed.

Comment: Do not use where clauses like "nazwa = null"; use "nazwa is null"

Comment: Thanks Steve, I used function Contains instead of Equals and now it is working : )

Comment: UPDATE  quizgame.dbo.uzytkownicy SET nazwa = LTRIM(RTRIM(nazwa))

Comment: Trailing spaces aren't significant in string comparisons in SQL Server. Post an MVCE.